# How to import OpenCV 4.5 in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv

The fact that this question is still occasionally getting new upvotes makes me think I'm not the only one in this kind of situation, so I've decided to write a step by step explanation of what worked for me in hope that others might find it useful in the future. Everything is based on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np2vX6ryj7I), but I think it's better to write a proper guide here in case it gets taken down.

If you're looking for help with OpenCV 3.4, [this](https://youtu.be/-0Yx1UzozzQ) is what I was following before trying version 4.5.

Comment: Did you see/follow: https://forum.opencv.org/t/run-samples-of-open-cv-in-android-studio/453/7

Comment: @MorrisonChang That seems more focused on compiling the library from source while I just need to import the release in Android Studio to use the autogenerated Java API.

Comment: I also had problems but I did make it work in the end so I have written steps in this answer of what worked (note that there are probably some not needed steps since it is meant for react-native)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59800761/how-can-i-import-opencv-library-to-react-native-project/64500728#64500728

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the complete procedure that currently works for me with OpenCV 4.5.2 on Android Studio 4.1.3.

1. In your project click on `File > New > Import Module...` and select the `/sdk` directory inside your OpenCV download. Give it a meaningful name and wait for the procedure to finish: the directory you selected should have been copied in the root of your project where the default `/app` directory resides;
2. open the Project Structure (for example by clicking on `File > Project Structure...`), then go to `Dependencies` (on the left), click on `app` and on the `+` icon in the `Declared Dependencies` tab (**not the one in the `Modules` tab**);
3. click on `Module Dependency` and select the checkbox for the OpenCV SDK that you imported earlier. You should now see it in the list with the other dependencies, so click on `Apply` and `OK` to exit from the Project Structure;
4. open the `build.gradle` file of your app module, copy the values of `compileSdkVersion`, `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`, then paste them in the `build.gradle` file of the OpenCV module replacing the default ones so they match exactly. You can also update the `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` fields to `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`;
5. finally, sync your project with Gradle files.

To check if it works, add this snippet to your code, for example in `MainActivity`:

```
if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
    Log.d("myTag", "OpenCV loaded")
}
```

Edit:
There's a minor addition with 4.8.0 OpenCV version.
Open the `app` level `build.gradle` file for org.opencv and add this block at the end of the android block:

```
buildFeatures {
    aidl = true
    buildConfig = true
}
```

Comment: This answer is still accurate when using Open CV 4.5.5 and Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1

Comment: @BenBloodworth Thank you for trying it out. By any chance could you point to some up to date resource on how to effectively use OpenCV for actually doing something non trivial? I had to ditch it completely due to the fact that I couldn't find good enough documentation on how to use the API. I used Google ML Kit instead, which worked flawlessly but obviously it's not open source.

Answer (score 2):

The sdk directory for opencv version 4.5.3 is "opencv/sources/modules/java/android_sdk". After doing each steps on the https://stackoverflow.com/a/65571017/9486652, i got some errors and i solved it by commenting or deleting the
'arguments "-DANDROID_STL=@ANDROID_STL@"' line which is found inside build.gradle of the opencv module.

```
    externalNativeBuild {
         cmake {
//          arguments "-DANDROID_STL=@ANDROID_STL@"
            targets "opencv_jni_shared"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had success to import opencv 4.5.2 in android studio. It is not so difficult. The key is to provide the correct OpenCV_DIR path for CMake to install the OpenCV.

Download SDK https://opencv.org/releases/

Import module by File > New > Import Module…

Add OpenCV module in setting.gradle

```
include "opencv"
project(":opencv").projectDir = file("sdk")
```

In application build.gradle, add OpenCV_DIR cmake argument under
android > defaultConfig > externalNativeBuild > cmake

```
arguments "-DOpenCV_DIR=" + file('../sdk').absolutePath + "/native/jni",
        "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang",
        "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
```

Add OpenCV module dependency in application build.gradle

```
implementation project(':opencv')
```

Link OpenCV library in your application cmake.

```
set(ANDROID_OPENCV_COMPONENTS "opencv_java" CACHE STRING "")
message(STATUS "ANDROID_ABI=${ANDROID_ABI}")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${ANDROID_OPENCV_COMPONENTS})
......
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${ANDROID_OPENCV_COMPONENTS})
```