# Error while Importing OpenCV on React Native App

Tags: android, react-native, opencv

**Note : im new to React Native and OpenCV**

so i want to use openCV on my react native app, it seems that there are only a few guide on this. One that i found is this article :
https://brainhub.eu/library/opencv-react-native-image-processing/

This article is quite confusing for me, which lead me to this thread :
[How can I import OpenCV library to React-Native project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59800761/how-can-i-import-opencv-library-to-react-native-project)

The reply with the most upvotes detailed on how to integrate openCV into react native, so i tried to follow the exact steps and when i run it the app always force close and give me this warning on Android Studio Logcat

> 7866-7976/com.reactnativeopencv E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
> at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
> at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:234)
> at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:29)
> at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:263)
> at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1293)
> at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1100(ReactInstanceManager.java:131)
> at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1023)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

The only difference that i make is that i added some import on **MainApplication.java** for RNOpenCVLibrary package and util.log

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log; //this

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.reactlibrary.RNOpenCvLibraryPackage; //and this

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
```

and i tried using build the app using `react-native start` and `react-native run-android` but the result is still the same

here's my react native info :

```
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19041
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8100 CPU @ 3.60GHz
    Memory: 402.28 MB / 7.95 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.18.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.22.10 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.14.6 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    Watchman: Not Found
 npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
    react-native: 0.64.1 => 0.64.1
    react-native-windows: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

does anyone know the answer to this error?

Answer (score 0):

hello i have recently done that, i honestly don't know what's the problem is it tutorial steps again or gradle versions or something else but somehow i got it working. I hope they upgrade their docs someday soon.

Here you can use my repo to build your app on top of it: [React-Native OpenCV 2021 Integration](https://github.com/lowkeyboard/may27-opencv-android)

The tutorial example of blurred image is working.

Edit:
The version numbers are important because if they're not compatible, gradle build will fail.

OpenCV library: 4.5.0
Gradle : 6.7
plugin: 4.1.0

also make sure to read android studio warnings and errors carefully,
as they tell you to also add maven() to your build.gradle files and change minSdkVersion to 21 as it is the minimum for react native 0.64,which again used in the example repo.

Not only on top level of build.gradle but change this versions anywhere these variables are mentioned so that gradle files will be in sync.

```
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
```

```
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
```

app level build.gradle, set your version to 1_8 as it is the compatible one in our case:

```
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```